# Kendo Mobile Action Sheet button tap not registering, but hard press is

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, cordova-plugins, kendo-mobile

I am a bit new to kendo mobile. I am using cordova and angularjs along with kendo UI to build a mobile IOS app. Like the title suggests within the action sheet, when clicking on one of the buttons the button is only fired if I press hard, when tapping on the button it only closes the action sheet. Is there a setting for kendo to register taps in its action sheet?

```
<ul kendo-mobile-action-sheet id="ActionSheet" k-popup='{"direction": "left"}'>
            <li></li>
            <li><a class="fa fa-camera" ng-click="GoTo('camera')" style="text-decoration: none; color: #000000;">&nbsp;Take Photo</a></li>
            <li><a class="fa fa-user" ng-click="GoTo('contactsedit')" style="text-decoration: none; color: #000000;" >&nbsp;Add Contacts</a></li>
            <li><a class="fa fa-comment" ng-click="GoTo('commentedit')" style="text-decoration: none; color: #000000;">&nbsp;Add Comment</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else that may be looking for help with something similar. ng-click is not very responsive in ios. I changed the ng-clicks in the list to data-actions and everything is working correctly.

```
   <ul kendo-mobile-action-sheet id="ActionSheet" k-popup='{"direction": "left"}'>
        <li></li>
        <li><a class="fa fa-camera" data-action="GoTo('camera')" style="text-decoration: none; color: #000000;">&nbsp;Take Photo</a></li>
        <li><a class="fa fa-user" data-action="GoTo('contactsedit')" style="text-decoration: none; color: #000000;" >&nbsp;Add Contacts</a></li>
        <li><a class="fa fa-comment" data-action="GoTo('commentedit')" style="text-decoration: none; color: #000000;">&nbsp;Add Comment</a></li>
    </ul>
```